# Regex - how to select all lines from a pattern to end of list

Tags: regex, list, match

Is it possible to sellect all lines from the last "Jhon Gerome" match (the bottom one) to the end of the list? is a clipboard text, Im using .Net Regex.

```
[2/3/2015 4:51:27 PM] *** Call to Bob Robinson ***
[2/3/2015 4:52:51 PM] Bob Robinson: check this out
[2/3/2015 4:55:34 PM] *** Call ended, duration 04:06 ***
[2/9/2015 7:52:58 PM] Jhon Gerome: you take to long
[2/25/2015 4:05:25 PM] Jhon Gerome: I am reading
[2/25/2015 4:05:26 PM] Jhon Gerome: ok
[3/10/2015 11:17:27 PM] Bob Robinson: how are you?
[3/10/2015 11:17:35 PM] Jhon Gerome: fine thanks
[3/10/2015 11:17:41 PM] Bob Robinson: are you there?
[3/10/2015 11:17:41 PM] Bob Robinson: can you hear me?
[2/25/2015 4:23:23 PM] *** Call from Bob Robinson ***
[2/25/2015 5:36:38 PM] *** Call ended, duration 1:13:15 ***
[3/10/2015 11:16:46 PM] *** Call to Bob Robinson, no answer.
Send video message ***
[3/10/2015 11:18:11 PM] Bob Robinson: whats up man
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] Bob Robinson: Jhon?
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] Bob Robinson: are you there?
```

Please see that all these lines end with a CRLF. Now what I first need to do match is...

```
fine thanks
[3/10/2015 11:17:41 PM] Bob Robinson: are you there?
[3/10/2015 11:17:41 PM] Bob Robinson: can you hear me?
[2/25/2015 4:23:23 PM] *** Call from Bob Robinson ***
[2/25/2015 5:36:38 PM] *** Call ended, duration 1:13:15 ***
[3/10/2015 11:16:46 PM] *** Call to Bob Robinson, no answer.
Send video message ***
[3/10/2015 11:18:11 PM] Bob Robinson: whats up man
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] Bob Robinson: Jhon?
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] Bob Robinson: are you there?
```

So far achieved using this code: (?s).*Jhon Gerome(\1) thanks to "Fede"

But then I will find all that is after >>>Bob Robinson: <<< so I will like to end with something like this, it doesn't matter it is in just one single line.

```
are you there?
can you hear me?
whats up man
Jhon?
are you there?
```

Is it possible ot achieve this with one single regex code? or maximum two? Any pointer? THanks.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, so that we have an idea of where you're getting stuck. As currently written, this comes across as a "gimme teh codez" question, which is [off-topic on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288133/211627).

Comment: Do you want the spaces before `fine thanks`?

Comment: ok on minute, looking throught my files

Comment: no, the spaces doesn't matter, in fact, it can be any of the two matches (last 2 codes) Iam using .Net Regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this with the `s` flag:

```
.*Jhon Gerome(.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD5lD0/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [385-852]   `: fine thanks
[3/10/2015 11:17:41 PM] Bob Robinson: are you there?
[3/10/2015 11:17:41 PM] Bob Robinson: can you hear me?
[2/25/2015 4:23:23 PM] *** Call from Bob Robinson ***
[2/25/2015 5:36:38 PM] *** Call ended, duration 1:13:15 ***
[3/10/2015 11:16:46 PM] *** Call to Bob Robinson, no answer.
Send video message ***
[3/10/2015 11:18:11 PM] Bob Robinson: whats up man
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] Bob Robinson: Jhon?
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] Bob Robinson: are you there?`
```

Or you can also use the inline flag:

```
(?s).*Jhon Gerome(.*)
```

Then you have to grab the capturing group content.

Comment: no, not woking. Using ___(?s).*Jhon Gerome(.*)___ select everything since it is single line. And using    ___.*Jhon Gerome(.*)___ select only the lines where Jhon Gerome is found.

Comment: I used this... ___(?s).*Jhon Gerome(.*)(\1)___ but it select exactly the opposite that I need, how can I invert the selection??? what do you mean by "grab the capturing group content" do you mean (\1) (\2) to select the created groups?? I did call (\1) but it grab the opposite that I want.

Comment: Thanks Fede, I did a replace text in order to catch the (\1) group, I just was wondering, is there anyway to use that captured group in the same regex code that it was captured from? Thanks Man

Comment: @litu16 the content you want is stored in the capturing group that you can access to by using `\1` or `$1`. You can check it in this **[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD5lD0/2)** in the `Substitution` section.

Comment: Yes, I know how to get what you said, but it's just that, the second half of the question is still unsolved, if I post another questions with the same example, moderator will ban me, sorry